# Apache, mod_jk and JBoss Load Balancing issue

Tags: apache, jboss, load-balancing, mod-jk

OK, I have been whacking my head in vain since the last three days over this, so time to take it up with the *gurus*!

**Background**
I'm trying to get an apparently simple setup working -- I have a CentOS box, on which I want to set-up two JBoss nodes (i.e. Two Nodes on a Single, Non-Multihomed, Server), and try out a fail-over scenario. I read that mod_jk module of Apache would help me achieve it.

I have diligently tried to follow [JBoss 5.1 Clustering Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/cluster_guide/5.1/html/index.html), but still, somehow, somewhere I seem to have fumbled.

**Issue**
I'm never able to connect to `node2` via Apache, and always get a *503 Service Unavailable* message.

**Configuration**
Following are the details.

```
CentOS 6
Apache 2.2.15
mod_jk 1.2.35
JBoss 5.1.0 GA
```

`httpd.conf` has the following line in the end:

```
#Include mod_jk's specific configuration file
Include conf/mod_jk.conf
```

`mod_jk.conf` contains the following line (amongst other things):

```
JkMountFile conf/uriworkermap.properties
```

`uriworkermap.properites` looks like this:

```
# Simple worker configuration file
# Mount the Servlet context to the ajp13 worker
/jmx-console=loadbalancer
/jmx-console/*=loadbalancer
/web-console=loadbalancer
/web-console/*=loadbalancer
/jspHello=loadbalancer
/jspHello/*=loadbalancer
```

`workers.properties`:

```
# Define list of workers that will be used
# for mapping requests
worker.list=loadbalancer,status

# Define Node1
# modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
worker.node1.port=8009
worker.node1.host=127.0.0.1
worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.lbfactor=1

# Define Node2
# modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
worker.node2.port=8109
worker.node2.host=127.0.0.1
worker.node2.type=ajp13
worker.node2.lbfactor=1


# Load-balancing behaviour
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=node1,node2
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1

# Status worker for managing load balancer
worker.status.type=status
```

I use the following commands to invoke `node1` and `node2`:

```
./run.sh -c node1 -g DocsPartition -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1 -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-default -b 0.0.0.0

./run.sh -c node2 -g DocsPartition -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=2 -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01 -b 0.0.0.0
```

Also, I have modified `server.xml` files within each of the `node` directories and added the corresponding `jvmRoute` parameter in `Engine` tag.

**Observation**
Following are the `mod_jk` logs:
*Initially when I bring up node1, node2 and httpd*

```
...
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (561): Truncated shared memory to 1856
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (606): Initialized shared memory /var/run/httpd/mod_jk.shm.14695 size=1856 free=1728 addr=0x7fe7cb7c3000
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] do_shm_open_lock::jk_shm.c (476): Opened shared memory lock /var/run/httpd/mod_jk.shm.14695.lock
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (589): Dump of map: 'ServerRoot' -> '/etc/httpd'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (589): Dump of map: 'worker.list' -> 'loadbalancer,status'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (589): Dump of map: 'worker.node1.port' -> '8009'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (589): Dump of map: 'worker.node1.host' -> '127.0.0.1'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (589): Dump of map: 'worker.node1.type' -> 'ajp13'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (589): Dump of map: 'worker.node1.lbfactor' -> '1'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (589): Dump of map: 'worker.node2.port' -> '8109'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (589): Dump of map: 'worker.node2.host' -> '127.0.0.1'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (589): Dump of map: 'worker.node2.type' -> 'ajp13'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (589): Dump of map: 'worker.node2.lbfactor' -> '1'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (589): Dump of map: 'worker.loadbalancer.type' -> 'lb'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (589): Dump of map: 'worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers' -> 'node1,node2'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (589): Dump of map: 'worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session' -> '0'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (589): Dump of map: 'worker.status.type' -> 'status'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] build_worker_map::jk_worker.c (241): creating worker loadbalancer
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (145): about to create instance loadbalancer of lb
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (158): about to validate and init loadbalancer
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (145): about to create instance node1 of ajp13
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (158): about to validate and init node1
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_validate::jk_ajp_common.c (2679): worker node1 contact is '127.0.0.1:8009'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2877): setting endpoint options:
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2880): keepalive:              0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2884): socket timeout:         0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2888): socket connect timeout: 0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2892): buffer size:            0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2896): pool timeout:           0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2900): ping timeout:           10000
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2904): connect timeout:        0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2908): reply timeout:          0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2912): prepost timeout:        0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2916): recovery options:       0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2920): retries:                2
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2924): max packet size:        8192
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2928): retry interval:         100
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_create_endpoint_cache::jk_ajp_common.c (2737): setting connection pool size to 1 with min 1 and acquire timeout 200
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (145): about to create instance node2 of ajp13
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (158): about to validate and init node2
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_validate::jk_ajp_common.c (2679): worker node2 contact is '127.0.0.1:8109'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2877): setting endpoint options:
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2880): keepalive:              0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2884): socket timeout:         0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2888): socket connect timeout: 0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2892): buffer size:            0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2896): pool timeout:           0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2900): ping timeout:           10000
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2904): connect timeout:        0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2908): reply timeout:          0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2912): prepost timeout:        0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2916): recovery options:       0
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2920): retries:                2
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2924): max packet size:        8192
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2928): retry interval:         100
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_create_endpoint_cache::jk_ajp_common.c (2737): setting connection pool size to 1 with min 1 and acquire timeout 200
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] validate::jk_lb_worker.c (1702): Balanced worker 0 has name node1 and route node1 in domain 
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] validate::jk_lb_worker.c (1702): Balanced worker 1 has name node2 and route node2 in domain 
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] update_mult::jk_lb_worker.c (262): worker node1 gets multiplicity 1
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] update_mult::jk_lb_worker.c (262): worker node2 gets multiplicity 1
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] jk_lb_push::jk_lb_worker.c (353): syncing shm for lb 'loadbalancer' from mem (0->1)
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] build_worker_map::jk_worker.c (241): creating worker status
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (145): about to create instance status of status
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (158): about to validate and init status
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] init::jk_status.c (5078): Status worker 'status' is read/write and has css '(null)', prefix 'worker', name space 'jk:', xml name space 'xmlns:jk="http://tomcat.apache.org"', document type '(null)'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [debug] init::jk_status.c (5129): Status worker 'status' has good rating for '0000000f' and bad rating for '00ff1010'
[Thu Sep 06 02:21:54 2012][14695:140633527957472] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3365): mod_jk/1.2.35 initialized
...
```

*And when I try to access the application*

```
...
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (949): Found a wildchar match '/jspHello/*=loadbalancer'
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2621): Into handler jakarta-servlet worker=loadbalancer r->proxyreq=0
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] wc_get_worker_for_name::jk_worker.c (115): found a worker loadbalancer
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] wc_maintain::jk_worker.c (338): Maintaining worker loadbalancer
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] wc_get_name_for_type::jk_worker.c (292): Found worker type 'lb'
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] init_ws_service::mod_jk.c (1097): Service protocol=HTTP/1.1 method=GET ssl=false host=(null) addr=::1 name=localhost port=80 auth=(null) user=(null) laddr=::1 raddr=::1 uri=/jspHello/
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1192): service sticky_session=0 id='empty'
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] get_most_suitable_worker::jk_lb_worker.c (1061): found best worker node2 (node2) using method 'Request'
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1237): service worker=node2 route=node2
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_get_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (3146): acquired connection pool slot=0 after 0 retries
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_marshal_into_msgb::jk_ajp_common.c (626): ajp marshaling done
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2441): processing node2 with 2 retries
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1615): (node2) all endpoints are disconnected.
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (485): socket TCP_NODELAY set to On
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (609): trying to connect socket 14 to 127.0.0.1:8109
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (627): connect to 127.0.0.1:8109 failed (errno=13)
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (992): Failed opening socket to (127.0.0.1:8109) (errno=13)
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1621): (node2) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=13)
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2614): (node2) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=1)
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2463): retry 1, sleeping for 100 ms before retrying
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1615): (node2) all endpoints are disconnected.
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (485): socket TCP_NODELAY set to On
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (609): trying to connect socket 14 to 127.0.0.1:8109
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (627): connect to 127.0.0.1:8109 failed (errno=13)
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (992): Failed opening socket to (127.0.0.1:8109) (errno=13)
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1621): (node2) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=13)
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2614): (node2) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2634): (node2) connecting to tomcat failed.
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_reset_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (786): (node2) resetting endpoint with socket -1 (socket shutdown)
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_done::jk_ajp_common.c (3077): recycling connection pool for worker node2 and socket -1
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1455): worker node2 escalating local error to global error
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [info] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1469): service failed, worker node2 is in error state
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1480): recoverable error... will try to recover on other worker
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] get_most_suitable_worker::jk_lb_worker.c (1061): found best worker node1 (node1) using method 'Request'
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1237): service worker=node1 route=node2
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_get_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (3146): acquired connection pool slot=0 after 0 retries
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_marshal_into_msgb::jk_ajp_common.c (626): ajp marshaling done
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2441): processing node1 with 2 retries
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1615): (node1) all endpoints are disconnected.
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (485): socket TCP_NODELAY set to On
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (609): trying to connect socket 14 to 127.0.0.1:8009
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (635): socket 14 [127.0.0.1:38909 -> 127.0.0.1:8009] connected
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_connection_tcp_send_message::jk_ajp_common.c (1175): sending to ajp13 pos=4 len=570 max=8192
[Thu Sep 06 02:24:42 2012][14700:140633527957472] [debug] ajp_connection_tcp_send_message::jk_ajp_common.c (1175): 0000    12 34 02 36 02 02 00 08 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31  - .4.6....HTTP/1.1
...
```

As you can see, it tries to connect to node2 twice before servicing the request via node1. This is so till the time `node1` is up. As soon as I take it down, I start getting the 503 error when I try to access.

I am not sure whether its a `mod_jk` issue or am I missing something.

Any suggestions?

**Update**:
It's working with two separate (physical) nodes, but I still could not get it to work on the same box with separate ports (8009 and 8109).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the JBoss isn't using the port you think it is. A good diagnostic tool is lsof (which is installable via yum);

```
lsof -i -n -P
```

and look to see what ports the JBoss process is listening to. Correct your configs from there.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it out and JBoss seems to be listening on both the port [8009, 8109] that were configured. Maybe it's some OS issue or something? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss may be listening on ports 8009 and 8109, but by default, it only listens on the 127.0.0.1 *interface* meaning that the ports would not be open to remote connections.

To make jboss listen on *all* interfaces, use this **run** option  (from **run.sh --help**):

> -b, --host=       Bind address for all JBoss services

and set the value to **0.0.0.0**

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this issue is to change the AJP port to a different range. The port 8109 was getting blocked by SELinux in my CentOS /Red Hat. So I changed the AJP port to 81 and the issue got fixed.